# RichTextBox text highlighting

Tags: c#

In my form there's a `UserControl` that has multiple `RichTextBox`'s and `TexBox`'s.

While tabbing into `TextBox`'s via keyboard, as soon as a `TextBox` get focus the entire text in it is highlighted in a blue background. Looks like a default behavior.

Now while tabbing into `RichTextBox`'s via keyboard, as soon as a `RichTextBox` get's focus, the cursor is shown inside the box and no text is `highlighted` with blue background. Probably a default behavior.

How can i make the `RichTextBox` also to highlight the text in blue background whenit get's focus via keyboard tabbing?

Comment: Do you mean the text is auto-selected, or the background color of the text is changed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use the `Enter` event and call the `SelectAll()` method.

```
private void richTextBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    richTextBox1.SelectAll();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to change the background color rather than select the text you can use something like the following.

```
    private void richTextBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        richTextBox1.BackColor = Color.LightBlue;
    }
    private void richTextBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        richTextBox1.BackColor = Color.White;
    }
```

Comment: This is not what am looking for, but giving you a +1